# max of numeric columns with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

Say, I have a dataframe `df` with some text and some numeric columns

```
species            | short | A    | B    | C 
-------------------+-------+------+------+-----
Homo sapiens       | hsa   | 0.1  | 0.2  | 0.7
Mus musculus       | mmu   | 0.3  | 0.7  | 0.0
Rattus norvegicus  | rno   | 0.0  | 1.0  | 0.0
```

I know that I can add a column computing the max of all columns using dplyr, but this works only if all columns are numeric:

```
df %>%
    rowwise() %>% 
    mutate(max_score = max(.))
```

How can I achieve the same, ignoring all non-numeric columns?

(Obviously, I could name `A, B, C` manually, but suppose I have a 'fat' data frame with many columns.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `select_if` with `is.numeric` to select numeric columns, and use `do.call(pmax, ...)` to calculate the rowwise maximum; `pmax` returns the parallel maxima of input vectors, since it takes vectors as individual argument, we can use `do.call` to pass all columns of `select_if`'s return (a data frame) as arguments to `pmax`:

```
df %>% mutate(max_score = do.call(pmax, select_if(., is.numeric)))

#            species short   A   B   C max_score
#1      Homo sapiens   hsa 0.1 0.2 0.7       0.7
#2      Mus musculus   mmu 0.3 0.7 0.0       0.7
#3 Rattus norvegicus   rno 0.0 1.0 0.0       1.0
```

Comment: Any way to include na.rm = F with this?